# HashSet equality c#

Tags: c#, equality, reflector, hashset

I have a HashSet with it's own EqualityComparer, but I am wondering if a simple count of both sets is used before checking each element?

I thought I would be able to answer this for myself in Reflector but I couldn't find any override of Equals in there.

Cheers,
Berryl

EDIT ==========

As Hans noted, it it the comparison of two sets that I am interested in, as part of an override of Equals in a class that has a HashSet as a property?

Comment: Can you post your code? The question sounds as if you are trying to compare two or more HashSet instances with each other rather than using the `IEqualityComparer<>` for evaluating what a given HashSet already contains.

Comment: @Anthony. I am trying to compare two sets as noted in the edit of my post. I am assuming the best way to do this would be to check the count and then the elements, although the element check could be expensive. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing it up.  Implementing your own IEqualityComparer<> is useful to compare the *elements* you put in the HashSet.  The Count property would only ever be useful if you want to compare the *sets*.  Two very different things.  There is no default implementation of Equals().  The HashSet.SetEquals() method indeed first checks the Count properties, if possible.